# Checksum md5sum mismatch when using Joystick

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I'm trying to let drone hover using motion capture system. However, it failed because of the joystick problem maybe.
It seems I should ask people who made drone, and actually I did, but didn't solved.
They say it might be a general ros question, so I am asking here.

The error is this.

```
client wants service /crazyflie/takeoff to have md5sum d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e, but it has b665b6c83a196e4774268cc26329b159. Dropping connection.
```

crazyflie is the name of the drone.
When I push the button which let drone takeoff, the error occurred.

How can I fix it?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/318827/checksum-md5sum-mismatch-when-using-joystick/) by [shmpwk](https://answers.ros.org/users/39767/shmpwk/) on ROS Answers with karma: 18 on 2019-03-19

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2019-03-20**:
Please describe your setup in more detail. I assume you have an on-board controller on the drone running ROS, as well as a Laptop/Desktop PC running ROS as well. Doublecheck that you do have the same ROS version on both systems and the same package version of the package containing the service definition.

**Comment by [shmpwk](https://answers.ros.org/users/39767/shmpwk/) on 2020-04-28**:
Sorry for late replying. You're right. Just the different version problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I deleted the package and tried another new package, and it works.

---

Originally posted by [shmpwk](https://answers.ros.org/users/39767/shmpwk/) with karma: 18 on 2020-04-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0